# Unable to create unlocked package on a dev hub org with Pardot installed

Tags: unlocked-package

My dev hub org has Pardot installed.
I have already successfully created a bunch of unlocked packages.
The package I am unable to create involves a new custom object with a master-detail relationship on the Account object.

The error I get when I run the command is:

`ERROR running force:package:version:create:  B2BMA Integration User: L'autorizzazione Leggi tutte le Economic_Document__c dipende dalle autorizzazioni: Leggi tutte le Account`

The error language is Italian because the integration user's language is Italian, I guess?
Both the profile and the user records are locked and I cannot modify them in any way.
Economic_Document__c is my custom object.

What I really don't understand is: why should the package creation complain about Pardot profile/user?

Comment: Did you list Pardot as a dependency in your sfdx-project.json? Did you include any profile settings at all in your package directories? What about permission sets? This error shouldn't happen unless you've managed to accidentally included more metadata than you meant (or, alternatively, you might also be *missing* metadata).

Comment: @sfdcfox I checked and doubled-checked but I couldn't find any mistaken reference to Pardot. I then, out of curiosity, tried to change the field type from master-detail to lookup - nothing else - and funnily enough I was able to create the package (1.0.0-1). Then I tried to change the field type back to master-detail and the error is still there. I really don't know how to overcome the problem.